# How to execute two simultaneous sqlite queries in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I want to do two DB operations at the same time in my iPad apps. At the same time I want execute two queries: one is an update query and the other is a select query.

I have tried with `dispatch_queue` but it is not working. Is it possible do these operations at the same time?

I am using a sqlite3 database.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can't do this.  If you succeeded you could corrupt the DB, or at least fetch bogus data.  Besides, how do you even define "at the same time", since you're potentially fetching data that is ambiguous?  Why is it not sufficient to do the two operations back-to-back?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. sqlite3 is not thread-safe. If you ever need to execute these operation simultaneously from two different threads (or queues) you need to lock DB handle so it will be used by only one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You `can't` and you `shouldn't`. Even if it is possible you will be getting unexpected results, because it is not predictable that you will get the old result set or the updated one. So, locks are assign to the table to handle such situations. So it is not possible. I would suggest to prioritize them.

**EDIT:**

From your last comment you posted that tells you have two controllers and from left pane the one goes out and the other goes in and both have either write or read operations.

You can follow these steps:

1. Once you detects that, another controller is going to load. first, start a UIActivityIndicator.
2. Run a request to update the current UIViewController's data to database.
3. Stop UIActivityIndicator and remove this UIViewController or change the right pane.
4. Load the new UIViewController. Start UIActivityIndicator.
5. Run request to load the data from database.
6. Stop UIActivityIndicator.
7. You are done.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there. any possible way to do the same??? In the mean time I want to show some loading signal for the next page

Comment: @Sourav - SQLite is not designed to allow simultaneous access from multiple threads.  In the best case you will get a SQLite error slapping your hand for trying.  In the worst case you will have corrupted data.

Comment: @Sourav - But note that a SQLite operation (on a local database) generally executes in the wink of an eye, so there is no perceptible "delay" due to ordering the operations vs somehow doing them simultaneously.